# how can i make this function correctly fulfill what they are asking me for?

Tags: javascript

> Iterate in a loop, increasing the received number by 2, up to a limit of 10 times. Save each new value in an array and return it. If at any point the sum value and the number of iterations coincide, the execution should be interrupted, and the string "Execution was interrupted" should be returned.

I have tried to make this function fulfill what they are asking me for, I have tried many ways but it only fulfills one of the two functions

This is the code

```
function breakStatement(num) {
  const nuevosValores = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    num += 2
    nuevosValores.push(num);

    if (num === i) {
      console.log('se interrumpe la ejecucion del programa');
      break;
    }

  }
  return nuevosValores;
}

console.log(breakStatement(-4));
```

i tried to loops while and for, but cant find the solution for this enunciated.

i get from the console this.

when the parameter is

```
console.log(breakStatement(-4));

Expected: "interrupted execution"
    Received: [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
```

and, when the parameter is

```
console.log(breakStatement(50));

Obtain a:

 Expected: [52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68]
    Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the error message.

Beside this, the loop should run only nine times, according to the wanted result.

```js
function breakStatement(num) {
    const nuevosValores = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        num += 2;
        if (num === i) return 'interrupted execution';
        nuevosValores.push(num);
    }

    return nuevosValores;
}

console.log(breakStatement(-4));
console.log(breakStatement(50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function breakStatement(num){
  const nuevosValores = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    num += 2
    nuevosValores.push(num);

    if (num === i) {
      console.log('se interrumpe la ejecucion del programa');
      break;
    }

  }

  return nuevosValores;
}

console.log(breakStatement(50));
```

seems like it's doing whats expected, so probably your issue is somewhere else in the code or just remember to return the error message

Comment: `console.log` is not the same as `return`.

Comment: yes you are correct. see the comment below the code sample...

Comment: thank you for you sass, you can vote for the other answer that modified the code and move along, this isn't reddit

Comment: Expected: [52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68]
Received: undefined.
it did not return undefined